# MS Charts Scrollbar option missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I am using scrollbar in mscharts. I am using using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` library.
But when I try to add scroll bar the otion is missing and I get the following error:

> Error 23  'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ScrollBar' and no extension method
>   'ScrollBar' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My chart is displaying properly but when the the range on X axis increase it overlaps the data points , so I want scroll bar. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am writing the following code to add scroll bar

```
    //Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
//Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable.Enabled = true; tried several version of this.
```

//this is where I putting the data in chart
 Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dataforChart1.Rows, "Version", "DateofReport", "CountofInstalls",String.Empty);

foreach (Series cs in Chart1.Series)
           {

```
          // cs.LegendText = cs.Name;

          Legend legend = new Legend(cs.Name);

          Chart1.Legends.Add(legend);
          Chart1.Legends[legend.Name].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
          cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;


           cs.BorderWidth = 2;
          cs.XValueMember = "DateofReport";
          cs.YValueMembers = "CountofInstalls";
           cs.ToolTip = "#VALY #VALX";
       }
      // Chart1.Legend.Location
        Chart1.DataBind();
```

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3OL5.jpg)

As you can see in the image I get an entire line for the data 2/10 and it overlaps with rest of the chart. If i reduce the range in X value it comes properly but I do not want to do that as I may need the entire range.

Comment: The `Axis` class does not have a `ScrollBar`, the scroll bar could possibly be part of another component of the `Chart`? // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried with AxisX.ScaleView.ScrollBar also but it wasn't there either. I cant even find the zoomable property in Scaleview. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Just look through the MSDN entries for those classes, I'd imagine autocomplete could also help a bit. Otherwise I've never worked with `Chart` directly so I am not sure about where or if it has the option.

Comment: In ASP.NET chart is rendered as static image by the browser. `Scrollbar` is available only in `WinForms`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I have line charts in the application so when ever the date range on X axis is too long it creates multiple line for the same data point and it seems that it is overlapping. I don't know how to get around that

Comment: If you don't post your code is very unlikely that anyone will bother to look into your problem. Read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I will post it.

Comment: I posted the code and the respective chart. thanks